# Who made the cartoon where the ping pong champion got beat by a kid, and can you share an image?

Tags: identification-request

I saw this cartoon a couple decades ago and I believe it was from *The Far Side* but I am not certain.

It showed a cowboy-style theme where the champion ping pong player (a king of the mountain) was finally beat by a skilled kid.

The caption was something like this:

> Well kid, you beat me. Now every paddle-packing player wanting to make a name
>   for himself will come lookin' for you instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a Far Side cartoon. In respect of Larson's request to not repost his comics online, I'm only posting a low-res version:
[image: Ping Pong gunslinger]

The text at the bottom:

> "Well, kid, ya beat me -- and now every punk packin' a paddle and tryin' to make a name for himself will come lookin' for you! ... Welcome to hell, kid."

Comment: I will admit that I don't know which collection this shows up. I will check tonight if someone doesn't scoop me on it.